# Allow All Users to Import Python Script

Tags: server, python, environment-variables

We have a JupyterHub server and it spawns Jupyter notebooks to users. I wrote a Python script and I want all users to be allowed to import it to their notebooks. There is a PYTHONPATH environment variable for single users, but how can I accomplish it for all users have a account on the system?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it by moving my module to `/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

Answer (score 0):

`/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` is your system Python's path.

You should never install nor manually move packages in there, as this may break your system, which relies in many ways on your system Python.

When you work with Python it is recommended to create a virtual environment. You can imagine this is a personal copy - just for one project.

This is necessary as different apps/projects depend on different versions of dependencies. This means, if you update a dependency for one project, and work with the global interpreter, you can break other apps.

When you want to share code locally on one machine between users, I'd put the code maybe under a new `/srv/your-name` folder. Obviously, you would have to set the Python path for all your users. But this is a low price compared to a broken system.

If you want to share code between different machines, you could think about either creating an online repository, like on e.g. GitHub or even create a Python package for PyPi.org.

Comment: Ok. Is there any simple way to set all user's Python path wtihout setting each one's PYTHONPATH variable or appending path with sys module?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, as there is only one global Python interpreter, which you should not use for above mentioned reasons.

Comment: Ok. Now I have an another problem. I logged into server with a normal user and then I changed .bashrc to make $PYTHONPATH point to my Python script. Then I tried to import it, but it failed.

Comment: Please create a new `question` for this and make sure to include everything what you did and the exact error message.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.